# ChromeCast - Stream Calls Failing when Stalled for long time

Tags: chromecast

I'm attempting to play a live stream on ChromeCast. The stream is thrown fine and starts playback appropriately.

However when I play the stream longer: somewhere between 2-15 minutes, the player stops playing and I get `MediaStatus.IDLE_REASON_ERROR` in my `RemoteMediaClient.Callback`.

When looking at the console logs from ChromeCast I see that 3-4 calls are failed. Here are the logs:

```
14:50:26.931 GET https://... 0 ()
14:50:27.624 GET https://... 0 ()
14:50:28.201 GET https://... 0 ()
14:50:29.351 GET https://... 0 ()
14:50:29.947 media_player.js:64  [1381.837s] [cast.player.api.Host] error: cast.player.api.ErrorCode.NETWORK/3126000
```

Looking at [Cast MediaPlayer.ErrorCode](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/mpl/error_codes) Error `312.*` is

> Failed to retrieve the media (bitrated) playlist m3u8 file with three retries.
>
> Developers need to validate that their playlists are indeed available. It could be the case that a user that cannot reach the playlist as well.

I checked, the playlist was available. So I thought perhaps the server wasn't responding. So I looked at the network calls response logs.

**Successful Request**
[image]

**Stalled Request**
[image]

Note that the stall time far exceeds the usual stall time.

ChromeCast isn't making these calls at all, the requests are simply stalled for a long time until they are cancelled. All the successful requests are stalled for less than 14ms (mostly under 2ms).

The [Network Analysis Timing Breakdown](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#timing-explanation) provides three reasons for stalling

> - There are higher priority requests.
> - There are already six TCP connections open for this origin, which is the limit. Applies to HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 only.
> - The browser is briefly allocating space in the disk cache

While I do believe the first one should not be the case, the later two can be. However in both cases I believe the fault lies with `cast.player`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Has anyone else faced the same issue? Is there any way to either fix it or come up with a work-around.

Comment: I faced the same issue if I open the chrome debugging tab(chrome://inspect). It looks like the agent collecting the network stats consumes to much memory. Does it also happen if you close the inspect tab and restart the device?

Comment: @Patrick not sure, but maybe. The issue was reported from the field when collecting logs I get the above error. Not sure if that is the case when not retrieving logs, and in truth can not be sure. Anyways no point discussing what could be without anyway to figure out if it really is.